# Sort Data with Two Columns Based on Matching Data on One Column

Tags: excel, sorting, match

I have two sets of data: Data Set 1 is in column A, while Data Set 2 is in two columns, B and C.  Column B has the same data as in column A, but just jumbled. I want to sort Data Set 2 based on the order of Data Set 1, while keeping the values in Data Set 2 (B+C) together. Highly appreciate anyone who can help me.

Comment: Not sure if I totally understand, but why not just select all three columns and then sort by Column A? That would solve your problem based on my interpretation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming site. How is this related to programming?

Comment: Are all records in Column A different?

Comment: Can you tell us which version of Excel you have plz?

Answer (score 0):

Different approaches can be used. I guess that all records of your Column A are different.
Method 1: Copy Column A to Column F, then use the vlookup function as follows.
[image]

Method 2: Insert Column B and use the match function as follows.
[image]

You now can sort columns B, C, D.